# TFS Test documentation: how to get "Automated test type" in a test case

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, test-plan

I would like to get a perfect test documentation and I miss a field when linked test cases to concrete tests between TFS and Visual Studio.

I search for a while but could not find any relevant documentation.

How to set / get set the field "Automated test type" in linked automation tab of a TFS test case description:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you. In MSDN you can find how to associate a test method with respective test case.

When you know the identifier of the work item for the test case:

If you are using Visual Studio 2017 or later, follow these steps to associate your tests.

If the **Test Explorer window** is not displayed, open it from the **Test | Windows** menu.

If your tests are not displayed in **Test Explorer**, build the solution.

In Test Explorer, select the test method you want to associate and choose **Associate** **to Test Case**.

In the dialog that opens, type the test case identifier and choose **Add Association**, then choose **Save**.

The dialog shows a list of test cases currently associated with the selected test method. You cannot associate more than one test method with a test case, but you can associate a test method with more than one test case.

[Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=tfs-2017)

Comment: Please be more detailed. Answers with only link is not good variant.